# Error in communicating between multiple topics stream listener kafka | Application ID not being picked up from .properties file

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am getting error in communication with kafka streams topics. When I try from 1st topic to 2nd topic, it works fine. but while sending from 2nd topic to 3rd topic, it errors out saying Failed to create consumer binding , retry in 30 seconds , Null pointer exception at registerconsumerproperties
On debugging I realised, the applicationID for 3rd topic is being passed as null , though even I have specified it explicitly

My application.properties file

```
## Topic 1
-  spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.destination=topic-1
-  spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.consumer.applicationId=processor-1


## Topic 2
-  spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output2.bindings=<topic-2 name>
-  spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input2.destination=<topic-2 name >
-  spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input2.consumer.applicationId=processor-2

## Topic 3
-  spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output3.destination=<topic-3 name>
-  spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input3.destination=<topic-3 name>
-  spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input3.consumer.applicationId=processor-3
```

```
1st listener

public classA {
@StreamListener
public void process(@INPUT(check.Const_A) KStream<String, StreamClass> stream)
 stream.foreach((key,value)-> System.out.println(key + value)));
stream.to(check.Const_B);
}
```

```
2nd listener
public classB {
@StreamListener
public void process(@INPUT(check.Const_C) KStream<String, StreamClass> stream)
 stream.foreach((key,value)-> System.out.println(key + value)));
stream.to(check.Const_D);
}
```

```
3rd listener
public classC {
@StreamListener
public void process(@INPUT(check.Const_E) KStream<String, StreamClass> stream)
 stream.foreach((key,value)-> System.out.println(key + value)));

}
```

```
Interface (to be added in @EnableBinding annotation)

public check {
String Const_A = "input1"
String Const_B="output2"
String CONST_C="input2"
String CONST_D="output3"
String CONST_E="input3"

@Input(Const_A)
KStream<String,StreamClass> inATopic();

@Output(Const_B)
MessageChannel outATopic();

@Input(Const_C)
KStream<String,StreamClass> inBTopic();

@Output(Const_D)
MessageChannel outBTopic();

@Output(Const_E)
KStream<String,StreamClass> outtCTopic();


}
```

I have even tried changing the names of each process with a different name but nothing seems to be working. Could someone please help in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After too much debugging , I realised I had missed the @Component annotation on the 3rd listener and hence Spring boot was not picking it up only

Comment: Also, FWIW, the `@StreamListener @Input, @Output` and annotation approach in general has been deprecated a while back and soon will not be supported

Comment: Oh is it!! What is the best approach for it now then? Normal Kafka listeners? I guess I missed reading it's being depreciated. Could you please point to some links. We definitely would need for longer run. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Just look at the docs. We switched to functional approach several years ago - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-producing-consuming-messages. There are also several blogs that you can benefit from https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/14/spring-cloud-stream-demystified-and-simplified, https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/17/spring-cloud-stream-functional-and-reactive

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like you are using the Kafka Streams binder. See this programming model section in the docs for the recommended ways to write processors using Kafka Streams: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_programming_model

Comment: Thank you so much! It was quite simple to convert annotations based approach to functional model :)